# Android webview вкладки

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview, webbrowser

Мне нужно сделать отображение сайта в приложении. 
Простого webview обычно хватает полностью, но сейчас на сайте есть возможность войти через фейсбук. 
Как работает на десктопе: Нажали войти через ФБ, открылось новое окно, ввели информацию, окно закрылось, вернулись назад к работе с сайтом. 
В вебвю такое не получается сделать, так он поддерживает  только одну вкладку.
Как можно реализовать подобное поведение?

Comment: Может просто открыть ФБ в той же `WebView`? А после авторизации goBack() или грузим нужную страницу.

Comment: Там точно новое окно открывается? Может iframe?